# Transparency in a 3D plot

Tags: plotting

How can I make the plane in the first image more like the plane in the second? More transparent, specially. I tried messing with the `Opacity` and `Mesh`, to no avail. Can someone help me? (you can disregard the vector completely)

[image]

Right now, the code for the first image is:

```
Show[Plot3D[{Sqrt[x^2 + y^2], -Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]}, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10},
       PlotStyle -> RGBColor[0.86`, 0.86`, 0.`, .1], Mesh -> None],
     Plot3D[1/5 (3 x + 4 y), {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10},
       PlotStyle -> RGBColor[1.`, 0.9`, 0.14`], PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.9],
       Mesh -> None],
     Graphics3D[Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, {-6, -8, 10}}]], 
   BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, Boxed -> False, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}]
```

Comment: You're trying to specify `PlotStyle` twice, which doesn't work (the second one is ignored). Use `Directive` to combine them instead: `PlotStyle -> Directive[RGBColor[1., 0.9, 0.14], Opacity[0.9]]`

Comment: Somehow I found myself here, and this 'Directive' did showed up. It sorta worked. Thank you! I think I'm going to delete the question, it was too basic to be here, no?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Show[
 Plot3D[{Sqrt[x^2 + y^2], -Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]}, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 
   10}, PlotStyle -> RGBColor[0.86`, 0.86`, 0.`, .1], Mesh -> None],

 Plot3D[1/5 (3 x + 4 y), {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, 
  PlotStyle -> Hue[0.3, 0.96, 0.54, 0.7], 
  MeshStyle -> Directive[Dashed, White, Opacity[.3]]],

 Graphics3D[Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, {-6, -8, 10}}]],


 BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, Boxed -> False, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}]
```

[image]